# How can I get these two sections next to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two sections that have to be next to each other on larger screen sizes. On smaller screen sizes the carousel has to be on top and the product information under it.

On small screen sizes it works but on larger screen sizes the carousel has a weird left margin that is on the `.container` class and I think that is what is blocking the other section from going next to the carousel

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const starRating = document.getElementById('star-rating');
  const stars = starRating.querySelectorAll('li');

  stars.forEach(star => {
    star.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
      resetStars();
      highlightStars(value);
    });
  });

  function resetStars() {
    stars.forEach(star => {
      star.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }

  function highlightStars(value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      stars[i].classList.add('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  background: #F4F4F4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100vh;
  width: calc(235vw - 220px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.carousel {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.carousel input {
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.carousel__slides .carousel__slide:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.carousel__slides .carousel__slide:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.carousel__slides .carousel__slide:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.carousel__thumbnails li:nth-of-type(1) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.carousel__thumbnails li:nth-of-type(2) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.carousel__thumbnails li:nth-of-type(3) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel__slides {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}

.carousel__slide figure {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel__slide div {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__slide img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}

.carousel__slide.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.carousel__thumbnails {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.carousel__slides+.carousel__thumbnails {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.carousel__thumbnails li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: calc((100% / 6) - 20px);
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__thumbnails label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__thumbnails label:hover,
.carousel__thumbnails label:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__thumbnails label img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__thumbnails img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    margin-right: -325px;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-origin: right;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 422px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    margin-right: -254px;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    transform-origin: right;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.star-rating {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.star-rating ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.star-rating li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.star-rating li::before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ccc;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.star-rating li:hover::before,
.star-rating li.selected::before {
  color: #0377BD;
}

.capacity {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.capacity li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.capacity label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: var(--color-background2);
  border: black solid;
  color: var(--color-background1);
}

.capacity input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.capacity input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
.Checked+label {
  background: var(--color-background1);
  color: var(--color-background2);
}

.capacity label:hover {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <input type="radio" name="slides" checked="checked" id="slide-1">
    <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide-2">
    <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide-3">
    <ul class="carousel__slides">
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <div>
          <img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m.webp" alt="wd black sn770m">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <div>
          <img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-hand.webp" alt="wd black sn770m in a hand">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <div>
          <img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-steamdeck.webp" alt="wd black sn770m with steamdeck">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="carousel__thumbnails">
      <li>
        <label for="slide-1"><img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m.webp" alt="wd black sn770m thumbnail"></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="slide-2"><img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-hand.webp" alt="wd black sn770m in a hand thumbnail"></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="slide-3"><img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-steamdeck.webp" alt="wd black sn770m with steamdeck thumbnail"></label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="data">
  <p>Part#: WDBDNH5000ABK-WRSN</p>
  <h1>WD_BLACK SN770M NVMe™ SSD</h1>
  <h2>from WD_BLACK</h2>
  <div class="star-rating" id="star-rating">
    <ul>
      <li data-value="1"></li>
      <li data-value="2"></li>
      <li data-value="3"></li>
      <li data-value="4"></li>
      <li data-value="5"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="capacity">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="500gb" name="capactity" checked="checked" />
      <label for="500gb">500GB</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="1tb" name="capactity" />
      <label for="1tb">1TB</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="2tb" name="capactity" />
      <label for="2tb">2TB</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: either flexbox or grid to the parent element or in case that you use Bootstrap you can use the Bootstrap grid. PC: Pay extra attention to the word **minimal** in [repro]. I doubt that 95% of your code is necessary to show the basic issue or attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:absolute` and as a distance: `left: 370px;`, to the `.container` class, like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const starRating = document.getElementById('star-rating');
  const stars = starRating.querySelectorAll('li');

  stars.forEach(star => {
    star.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
      resetStars();
      highlightStars(value);
    });
  });

  function resetStars() {
    stars.forEach(star => {
      star.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }

  function highlightStars(value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      stars[i].classList.add('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  background: #F4F4F4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100vh;
  width: calc(235vw - 220px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.carousel {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.carousel input {
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.carousel__slides .carousel__slide:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.carousel__slides .carousel__slide:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.carousel__slides .carousel__slide:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.carousel__thumbnails li:nth-of-type(1) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.carousel__thumbnails li:nth-of-type(2) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.carousel__thumbnails li:nth-of-type(3) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel__slides {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}

.carousel__slide figure {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel__slide div {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__slide img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}

.carousel__slide.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.carousel__thumbnails {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.carousel__slides+.carousel__thumbnails {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.carousel__thumbnails li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: calc((100% / 6) - 20px);
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__thumbnails label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__thumbnails label:hover,
.carousel__thumbnails label:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__thumbnails label img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__thumbnails img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    margin-right: -325px;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-origin: right;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 422px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    margin-right: -254px;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    transform-origin: right;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.star-rating {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.star-rating ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.star-rating li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.star-rating li::before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ccc;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.star-rating li:hover::before,
.star-rating li.selected::before {
  color: #0377BD;
}

.capacity {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.capacity li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.capacity label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: var(--color-background2);
  border: black solid;
  color: var(--color-background1);
}

.capacity input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.capacity input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
.Checked+label {
  background: var(--color-background1);
  color: var(--color-background2);
}

.capacity label:hover {
  background: #DDD;
}
/*new code from here*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    left: 370px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <input type="radio" name="slides" checked="checked" id="slide-1">
    <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide-2">
    <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide-3">
    <ul class="carousel__slides">
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <div>
          <img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m.webp" alt="wd black sn770m">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <div>
          <img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-hand.webp" alt="wd black sn770m in a hand">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <div>
          <img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-steamdeck.webp" alt="wd black sn770m with steamdeck">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="carousel__thumbnails">
      <li>
        <label for="slide-1"><img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m.webp" alt="wd black sn770m thumbnail"></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="slide-2"><img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-hand.webp" alt="wd black sn770m in a hand thumbnail"></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="slide-3"><img src="/WesternDigital/images/wd-black-sn770m-steamdeck.webp" alt="wd black sn770m with steamdeck thumbnail"></label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="data">
  <p>Part#: WDBDNH5000ABK-WRSN</p>
  <h1>WD_BLACK SN770M NVMe™ SSD</h1>
  <h2>from WD_BLACK</h2>
  <div class="star-rating" id="star-rating">
    <ul>
      <li data-value="1"></li>
      <li data-value="2"></li>
      <li data-value="3"></li>
      <li data-value="4"></li>
      <li data-value="5"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="capacity">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="500gb" name="capactity" checked="checked" />
      <label for="500gb">500GB</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="1tb" name="capactity" />
      <label for="1tb">1TB</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="2tb" name="capactity" />
      <label for="2tb">2TB</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```